# Large matrix sparse in values

Tags: python, data-representation

How do I store and manipulate a large matrix in Python?

Its dimension is N*(N - 1)/2 x N*(N - 1)/2 where N is 5000. It's not sparse either so I couldn't use scipy sparse matrix representation. However, the values are integers ranging from 0 to 5.

**UPDATE:**
This is a pairwise comparison test applied to pairs (N*(N-1)/2), thus it quickly becomes too large ( **O(N<sup>4</sup>)** ).

Comment: I wonder if it is even possible. 0-5 can be represented using (a little less than) 3 bits. There are 8 bits in a byte, meaning that we need a storage of `((N*(N - 1)/2)**2) * 3 / 8 == 58570314843750` bytes, or more than 50 000 GB of data. Is there more structure to the data that is possible to use, to compress it?

Comment: It might also help if we knew what you were actually trying to *represent* with your data. The `n*(n-1)/2` sizing makes me think there must be some pattern in play here.

Comment: @JohanL: you're right, theoretically it's still too large.

Comment: 50'000 GB of data ~ 50 TB of data. It's certainly possible to store, however what generates this amount of data, and you want to be able to manipulate it (I presume: efficiently)?